# handle Exceptions from API server in client server

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

I am trying to  learn how to handle exception in APIs servers so I followed [this](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling) where he has built API for birds, he finally reached to APIs like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/params")
public Bird getBirdRequestParam(@RequestParam("birdId") Long birdId) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    Bird bird = birdRepository.findOne(birdId);
    if(bird == null){
        throw new EntityNotFoundException(Bird.class, "id", birdId.toString());
    }
    return bird;
}
```

and the ControllerAdvice has a method:

```
@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEntityNotFound(
        EntityNotFoundException ex) {
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(NOT_FOUND);
    apiError.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
}
```

the response will be a bird like this

```
{
"id": 1,
"scientificName": "Atlantic canary",
"specie": "serinus canaria",
"mass": 10,
"length": 11
}
```

or an exception details like this:

```
{
"apierror": {
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "timestamp": "09-04-2018 10:11:44",
    "message": "Bird was not found for parameters {id=2}"
}
```

but the problem is with my server that contacts with API

I am using :

```
public void gett(@RequestParam Long id) {
    ResponseEntity<Bird> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8181/params" + id, Bird.class);
    bird = responseEntity.getBody();
    model.addAttribute("birdform", bird);
    return "bird";
}
```

the `getForEntity` is waiting for a response with bird body but an exception may be thrown in server and the response may be json of the error.

how to handle this problem in my client server?

in other words :

how to know in my client server that the api server has thrown an exception in json form.???

I have tried to get the response in "Object" variable and then try to know if it was excption or bird  with "instance of" expression like this code

```
@GetMapping("/getbird")
public String getAll(@RequestParam Long id, Model model) {
    ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8181/api/bird/getone?id=" + id, Object.class);
    if (responseEntity.getBody() instanceof Bird.class) {
        Bird bird= (Bird) responseEntity.getBody();
        model.addAttribute("Bird", bird);
        return "bird-form";
    }
    else{
        // something else
        return "someview";
    }
}
```

but first thing it didnot work (the instance of always return false)

the second thing is that this is a hard work to do with all my controllers' actions.

I hope that i could explain my problem clearly .

thanks....

Comment: IMHO, your controller (that returns "bird" with a model) should not the one who calls the external api via restTemplate. A better approch would be to create something that will be an "ExchangeService" that will be the client class to the external api. That service will expose its own contract(return null if not found Or throw an exception or whatever) to your controller.

Comment: thank you for your answer  me @AkliREGUIG you are right from designly view, I should do service to deal with api. but this dont help us in the problem of compatibility between types(bird and exception)

Comment: Oh, yes. Didn't understand the question. The methods that are in your '@ControllerAdvice' or the methods annotated by '@ExceptionHandler' can return an ApiError Object when your controller's method will return the Bird Object.

Comment: @AkliREGUIG  i want to distinguish the json response and according to it I will act, I don't want to return json again in my clint server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check the body of the response to see if you got an error. `restTemplate.getForEntity()` (and other methods) would throw an `HttpClientErrorException` if you get a 4XX response, or `HttpServerErrorException` if you get a 5XX response from the call.

To catch these exceptions, you can define a `@ControllerAdvice` with proper methods for exception handling:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)  // 500
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
    public ApiError handle4xxFromClient(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
        // construct and return a custom ApiError object
    }
}
```

See https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc for details.

Comment: thank you for answering me, but this @ControllerAdvice already exists in Api server, the problem is how to know that the json (that i get as response)  are exception or an Entity?????

Comment: I have edited the question , I hope that will explain more about my problem.

Comment: You don't need to check the body of the response to see if you got an error. restTemplate.getForEntity() (and other methods) would throw an HttpClientErrorException if you get a 4XX response, or HttpServerErrorException if you get a 5XX response from the call.

Comment: thank you , thank you that exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions :

1. Use a custom implementation error handler in your reste template.
   `restTemplate.setErrorHandler(customerErrorHandler)`
2. Use the `http status`, rest template will throw an exception if it gets a *bad http status* from the server it is querying. Catch the exception and get the ApiError Object from the exception, and then throw and exception of your own that will be handled by your exception handler in your client server.

For these solutions to work, the server your are querying needs to send the right http status code when something wrong happens.